# vba how to search for a word and then add a column with a specific term?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to find a way to search for a phrase "term" in column "B" and then to add some text "new text" in a new column "I". I'm new to VBA and the code I have currently doesn't add any text:

```
    Sub addclm()

Dim row As Long
Dim column As Long
Dim strsearch As String
Dim rfind As Range
Dim sfirstaddress As String

strsearch = "term"
row = Sheet4.Range("I4").row
column = Sheet4.Range("I4").column


With Sheet4.Columns("B:B")
    Set rfind = .Find(strsearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rfind Is Nothing Then
sfirstaddress = rfind.Address
Sheet1.Cells(row, column) = "new text"
row = row + 1


End If
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You should avoid dimming your own variables such as **Row** and **Column** since VBA makes use of these. Try *MyRow* or *MyCol* instead. (This isnt your issue, but a highly recommended tip to follow)

Comment: Perhaps "term" is not found.

Comment: is there a way to check if the .find function is working?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in what you're trying to do? In words, what do you want your code to do?

Comment: `msgbox rfind.value` after you set rfind.

Comment: Basically I want to add a phrase "new text" in a new column "I" for rows with a specific phrase "term" in column "B" while leaving the rows without the phrase "term" blank.

Comment: Ok when I add the line msgbox rfind.value it gives me an error box that says "object variable or with block variable not set"
So is my .find function not executing properly?

Comment: that means `Find` returns nothing, so the term you're searching for doesn't exist in the range you're searching.

Comment: Also note that you're writing "new text" to `Sheet1`, while you're searching against `Sheet4` so even if `Find` returns something, you might not be adding the "new text" on the correct sheet.

Comment: ah you're right about the new text, I overlooked that.
 
 When I manually filter the column the term is there, so i guess there's a syntax problem in my find func.
 
 The term I'm searching for is usually shared with multiple other terms in the same cell, which is why I used LookAt:=xlPart but could that be a potential problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you want to do exactly, but this is my best guess at what you are wanting given the info you have provided. Paste this in a **module**, not a worksheet.

1. Determine what range to scan (Sheet4, ColB, Last Used Cell up to B2)
2. Loop through each Cell looking for "term"
3. If found, go to sheet1, paste value "new text" on corresponding ROW
4. If not found, do nothing
5. Loop 2-4 until all range is covered

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Sub addclm()

   Dim WB As Workbook
   Set WB = ThisWorkbook

   Dim strsearch As String
   strsearch = "term" 'what to search for in each cell in B

   Dim LRow As Long 'Determine the last row in B to limit loop
   LRow = WB.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B" & WB.Sheets("Sheet4").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

   Dim MyCell As Range
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Set MyRange = WB.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B2:B" & LRow) 'Where to loop (From bottom last row to B2)

   For Each MyCell In MyRange
       If InStr(MyCell.Text, strsearch) > 0 Then
           WB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & MyCell.row) = "new text"
       End If
   Next MyCell    
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Update the syntax (refer to sheets and ranges like I did above). Then step through your code using F8. You can hover over variables and it will tell you their current value. If it errors out, you will see what line

Comment: Ok using your advice I've been able to update another module I wrote to be much more efficient; using f8 (which I didn't know existed before) has helped immensely. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: also how would i go about setting a range for a table of values without using specific coordinates (so more general than like A3:H50)?

Comment: haha alright I'll upload it after I finish the rest of the macros

Comment: You will need to use some combination of a range and a variable. You can see how I set a dynamic range on my solution using LRow.